# Show my visit count/consecutive days on the activity view

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, consecutive-days

I sometimes like to just visit my profile to see how many consecutive days i'm at. On the old profile, that's easy:

[image: All the info is right there]

However, with the new split profile, it is only shown on the "profile" page, and only when i'm logged in.

[image: Consecutive count shown while logged in] [image: Not shown while logged out]

I thought the profile view was for *other* people... and here you're showing something only to me. That wouldn't even be so bad, except that it is not shown on the activity page, which is the default for my own:

[image: Not shown in activity view]

I think it would make sense to move it to the activity view.